# a.coord[jc] is not a function

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know why I might get the following error in Google Maps API V3?

`a.coord[jc] is not a function`

I am updating from v2 and I get the error when placing certain markers on the map... The marker objects all appear to be similar enough to make this work, but some cause this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We need more code than that. Please supply all the code you are using to create and access the marker.

Also V3 is very different to V2 so you will not be able to use the same code.